# Strong password check

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I need a regular expression that checks if passwords:

- are at least **8 characters**
- contain at least **1 uppercase** letter
- contain at least **1 lowercase** letter
- contain at least **1 number** or at least **1 special character**
- do **not** repeat a character **more than 2 times in row**

Examples that should match:

- Test1234!
- Te123stE

Examples that should not match:

- Teeest123!
- !TESTT1234

This is what I tried so far:

```
^(?!.*pass|.*Pass|.*qwer|.*Qwer)(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$
```

I don't know how to match the repeating characters. Any ideas?

Comment: By "contain 1..." I think you mean "contain at least 1..." :)

Comment: I also don't see how "Teeest123!" fails. It has 10 characters, 1 upper, 5 lower, 3 numbers, 1 special, and doesn't repeat any more than 3 times.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb there are 3 “e” chars so if it fails it’s because OP means “not 3 times”

Comment: @Bohemian - The condition says "do not repeat **more than** 3 times"

Comment: To prevent a character repeating **more than** 3 times, you may add this negative Lookahead: `(?!.*?(?:(.).*?\1){2})`. To prevent a character repeating 3 times or more, you may add this negative Lookahead: `(?!.*?(.).*?\1.*?\1)`.

Comment: @Bohemian then OP needs to explicitly say "not 3 times". What they *did* say has a totally different meaning. Not to mention that checking for exactly 3 (but more or less being ok) is oddly specific and I don't necessarily think it's safe to assume that's what they meant. More likely it's a bad test case.

Comment: I edited my question. Thanks for pointing out the mistakes.

Comment: @Mihaela Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I tried. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to fail the match if there are 3 or more *consecutive* identical chars, use `(?!.*(.)\1{2})` lookahead:

```
^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^0-9#?!@$%^&*-]*[0-9#?!@$%^&*-])(?!.*[pP]ass|.*[qQ]wer)(?!.*(.)\1{2}).{8,}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JXEsZN/2/).

If you want to fail the match if there are 3 or more *not necessarily consecutive* identical chars, use `(?!.*(.).*\1.*\1)` lookahead:

```
^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^0-9#?!@$%^&*-]*[0-9#?!@$%^&*-])(?!.*[pP]ass|.*[qQ]wer)(?!.*(.).*\1.*\1).{8,}$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JXEsZN/1)

**NOTE** the changes: the most efficient lookaheads are moved to the beginning (right after `^`) and the least efficient are moved to the right.

The most common lookaheads that check lower, upper case letters and special/digit chars are enhanced according to the [**principle of contrast**](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])` - there must be at least one uppercase ASCII letter
- `(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])` - there must be at least one lowercase ASCII letter
- `(?=[^0-9#?!@$%^&*-]*[0-9#?!@$%^&*-])` - there must be at least one special char from the `0-9#?!@$%^&*-` set (digit or `#`, `?`, `!`, `@`, `$`, `%`, `^`, `&`, `*`, `-`)
- `(?!.*[pP]ass|.*[qQ]wer)` - no `pass`/`Pass` and `qwer`/`Qwer` in the string allowed
- `(?!.*(.).*\1.*\1)` - no three not necessarily consecutive repeating chars allowed
- `.{8,}` - eight or more chars other than line break chars
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: The first regex it's almost what I need. It matches this string: TESTREGEX and it shouldn't, as it does not contain any lowercase letter and number/special character.

Comment: @Mihaela None of the regexps posted in my answer match `TESTREGEX`, see [regex #1](https://regex101.com/r/JXEsZN/3) and [regex #2](https://regex101.com/r/JXEsZN/4) demos

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
/
(?=.*[0-9#?!@$%^&*-])       # 1+ digit or special char
(?=.*[A-Z])                 # 1+ uc letters
(?=.*[a-z])                 # 1+ lc letters
(?=[a-zA-Z0-9#?!@$%^&*-]*$) # all chars valid
(?!.*(.)\1{2})              # no 3+ repeats
.{8,}                       # match string if length >= 8
/x                          # free-spacing mode
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0IIeEk/3/)